# Saving in pygtk

Tags: save, pygtk

I'm writing an app using pygtk and I was wondering how would my app be able to save data on the user's computer. I plan to distribute this across windows and unix. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module.

It serializes data, so that you can retrieve it in it's native Python form later.

It uses the `file()` object, so it's cross-platform, and can handle basically any object,
and it is even good with custom classes. The only thing I **know** it cannot serialize is a function.

---

Short use explenation:

```
import pickle
# Create an object
array = [1, "foo", Exception()]
# Serialize it
pickle.dump(array, open("settings.dat", "w"))
# Unserialize it
array = pickle.load(open("settings.dat"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do. I personally prefer using [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is a very easy to use database with Python bindings. (It also offers you the freedom to save with your own file extension.) The disadvantage to that is that SQLite3 databases can be viewed by notepad (albeit, cryptically).